# Is it possible to change the sdk version of the specific flutter plugin .ie. admob_flutter

Tags: android, flutter, performance, flutter-dependencies

The developer of the plugin admob_flutter is not maintaining the plugin anymore, as google play store is depreciating the com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:19.1.0
Is it possible to change the sdk version of the plugin in the app .

The developer of the plugin admob_flutter is not maintaining the plugin anymore.